# Comparative analysis between two landcover classifications from different models in R

Tags: raster, r, spatial-statistics

I have two `landcover` classifications computed via `random forest` and `maximum likelihood classification models` in `R`. I am trying to compare the two in `R`. One way I thought was to do simply compute the difference between the two and plot the `histogram`(using the `rasterVis` package) as shown below. Another approach I am thinking of is to create `ECDF` plots between the two. What would be a good method/test to do this kind of `spatial similarity` analysis in `R`?

[image]

Comment: I would poke around on the site as variations of this question have been addressed previously. Take a look at the t-test or kappa. There is a function that implements a few statistics in the spatialEco package. Really not sure how a cumulative distribution function would work here but you could perform a simple cross tabulation.

Comment: This difference histogram plot is the sums of the diagonals of the cross-tabulation. You'll get more info from the cross-tabulation itself which from your X-axis here I guess would be an 11x11 matrix with a large value on the main diagonal showing all the cell predictions that agree. But there's not really a statistical question here (yet...).

Comment: @Spacedman,well a question could be what is the agreement between the land cover classifications from the two models?

Comment: That's a *numeric* question, not a statistical one. The answer is "R1-R2", and what you've histogrammed is meaningless beyond the 0 because the numeric value of classes are labels and arbitrary. If you have predictions and uncertainties from your models then you can maybe test if the models are statistically different. You'd need to get the P(class=X) for all classes X in each pixel. Then if method A says P(grass=0.99) and B says P(desert=0.99) for some pixel then that's a significant difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the recommendation from Jeffary Evans. I was able to create a simple cross tabulation in `R`.

Code

```
library(raster)
library(spatialEco)
library(RStoolbox)

# Run the Random Forest (RF) model
Land_Cover_Classification_RF = superClass(img = raster_stack, model = "rf", trainData = training_points, responseCol = "class", filename = "path/Land_Cover_Classification_RF.tif")

# Run the Maximum Likelihood Classification (MLC) Model

Land_Cover_Classification_MLC = superClass(img = raster_stack, model = "mlc", trainData = training_points, responseCol = "class", filename = "path/Land_Cover_Classification_MLC.tif")

# Create Cross Tabulation on the two classifications

# First load the rasters
Land_Cover_Classification_RF _rst = raster("path/Land_Cover_Classification_RF.tif")
Land_Cover_Classification_MLC _rst = raster("path/Land_Cover_Classification_MLC.tif")

# Create cross tabulation
RF_MLC_CT = cross.tab(Land_Cover_Classification_RF,
                      Land_Cover_Classification_MLC,
                      pct = T)

# Convert to a dataframe
RF_MLC_CT_df = as.data.frame(RF_MLC_CT)

# Save as a CSV 
write.csv(RF_MLC_CT_df,
          "path/RF_MLC_CT.csv")
```